# qTip styles not working for me, on any qtips, made by anyone, on any browser?

Tags: qtip2

I'm trying to get qTip working on my own project, and the qTips do show up, but without styling. I've tried googling and poking around Stackoverflow, but to no avail.

For example, if I look at the qTip demo page, [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#imagemap), I *can* see the styling. But when I click the `jsfiddle` button on the top left corner, (which takes me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/v2WPz/)) the styling is gone.

Anyone know what's going on? It makes it impossible to style my own qTips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the code is a bit different on those two pages

in the original/styled the it use `classes: 'qtip-tipsy qtip-shadow'`

while on jsfiddle it use `classes: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow'`

change on the jsfiddle to `classes: 'qtip-tipsy qtip-shadow'` and its all good...

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it. Now, why isn't that in the qTip2 documentation? They still have there to use the classes 'ui-tooltip-tipsy' or whatever, in the style section of the documentation.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like those one got some meaning when using jQuery UI themes... why are they in the original jsfiddle ? don't know

Comment: ah, good point (re the UI themes). It's probably documented somewhere. Thanks for the help :)